# Simple email-regexp doesn't allow hyphen before and after @

Tags: regex, validation, email

I found this simple regexp (i know it's probably not perfect) somewhere online to validate an email address.

```
/^(?:\w+\.?)*\w+@(?:\w+\.)+\w+$/
```

The problem is, that this regexp doesn't allow for the following case:

```
myname@test-domain.com
my-name@test-domain.com
```

Any ideas?

ps. I'm using this regexp within javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you simply want to add hyphens you can change the regexp to:

```
/^(?:\w+[\-\.])*\w+@(?:\w+[\-\.])*\w+\.\w+$/
```

To add other special chars e.g. like underscore just put them in the *first* (not the *second*) pair of square brackets, i.e. change `[\-\.]` to `[\-\._]`.

Also have a look on [this question and its anwer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)